# In angular 2, how to display a number as two decimal rounded currency?

Tags: filter, rounding, angular, currency

Examples:

- 1.99  --> $1.99
- 1.9   --> $1.90
- 1     --> $1.00
- 1.005 --> $1.01
- 1.004 --> $1.00

I am using `{{num | currency:'USD':true}}` but it does not show trailing 0s.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Use this code. Here is a working example http://plnkr.co/edit/xnN1HnJtTel6WA24GttR?p=preview
`{{num | currency:'USD':true:'1.2-2'}}`

***Explanation :***
***number_expression | number[:digitInfo]***

Finally we get a decimal number as text. Find the description.

**number_expression:** An angular expression that will give output a number.

**number :** A pipe keyword that is used with pipe operator.

**digitInfo :** It defines number format.

Now we will understand how to use digitInfo. The syntax for digitInfo is as follows.

***{minIntegerDigits}.{minFractionDigits}-{maxFractionDigits}***

Find the description.

**minIntegerDigits :** Minimum number of integer digits. Default is 1. (in our case 1)

**minFractionDigits :** Minimum number of fraction digits. Default is 0. (in our case 2)

**maxFractionDigits :** Maximum number of fraction digits. Default is 3. (in our case 2)

Comment: @g.sui please mark as answer now that you have the rep

Comment: Soooooo verbose, as with everything Angular 2. Is there a way to set these options as default?  (I found nothing promising in the docs)

Comment: This solution does not work in safari. When i open this link - http://plnkr.co/edit/xnN1HnJtTel6WA24GttR?p=preview in safari. It doesn't show expected output.

Comment: How about not roundup for 1 decimal place?

Ex: 12.9999 => 12.9

Answer (score 19):

well you got the correct answer but still i think i can elaborate more this answer so posting it as answer:

First of all there are number of pipes available of the angular2 to use in our project some of them are listed below

> CurrencyPipe , DatePipe, UpperCasePipe, LowerCasePipe, and PercentPipe and many more.

Here as your question you have problem related to currency pipe. so i want to explain bit more as other answers.

## CurrencyPipe :

A pipe may accept any number of optional parameters to fine-tune its output. We add parameters to a pipe by following the pipe name with a colon ( : ) and then the parameter value (e.g., currency:'EUR'). If our pipe accepts multiple parameters, we separate the values with colons (e.g. slice:1:5).

{{number | currency:'your_type':true:'1.2-2'}}

here...first parameter is currency type which is either EUR,USD or anything, Second parameter is true/false for the `symbolDisplay` which is false byDefault. then Third one is range limit basically a range limit . You can set a min and max length after the decimal point and a fixed number (or leave it blank for default) for the places before the decimal point.

I have found some good tutorials for the pipes in the angular2 which i am posting here..

http://voidcanvas.com/angular-2-pipes-filters/

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html

Hope it Helps and clarify more about pipes !!
@Pardeep !!

Answer (score 11):

You are using the correct pipe. You just need to add the digit info to the output.

`{{num | currency:'USD':true}}` should be...

`{{num | currency:'USD':true:'1.2-2'}}`

For reference: `'USD'` represents the type of currency, `true` represents whether to show the currency symbol ($), and `'1.2-2'` represents the digit info.

The digit info is `{minIntegerDigits}.{minFractionDigits}-{maxFractionDigits}`.

`minIntegerDigits` is the minimum number of integer digits to use and defaults to 1.
`minFractionDigits` is the minimum number of digits after fraction and defaults to 0.
`maxFractionDigits` is the maximum number of digits after fraction and defaults to 3.

Source for the digit info can be found here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/DecimalPipe-pipe.html

Answer (score 9):

If, like me, you're trying to do this in the typescript/javascript rather than HTML, you can also use [toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString#Browser_Compatibility)

So to convert a number to a currency string:

```
  ppCurrency(number) {
   return number.toLocaleString('en-US', { style: 'currency', currency: 'USD' });
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

Following will convert with 2 decimal digits

```
{{num | currency : '$' : 2}}
```

angular 2

```
{{num | currency:'USD':true:'1.2-2'}}
```

Comment: this is not correct method to use `$` directly instead you have to use predefined syntax for the currency like `USD` or `EUR` or something like that.

Comment: I have to add that I lost some precious minutes by having the template load with the model value being undefined.
You need to set an initial value for the number that is going to be currency piped or else it wont at all work.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="number" [(ngModel)]="myModel" (keyup)="onBlurMethod()">
<br>
<br> The formatted currency is :
<br> {{myModel | currency:'USD':true:'1.2-2' }}
```

Here is the working example.

http://plnkr.co/edit/pSK8p7u3oo4WsAB9aFBS?p=preview

Comment: Yes its same only difference is text field is working.

Comment: does't matter i think...question is related to pipe is't it ?

Answer (score 0):

If any body gets a warning and wanted to resolve it, please find below the fix I used.

Following is the warning Angular displays in browser console:

> Warning: the currency pipe has been changed in Angular v5. The
> symbolDisplay option (third parameter) is now a string instead of a
> boolean. The accepted values are "code", "symbol" or "symbol-narrow".

The format that causes the warning: `currency: "USD":true:"1.2-2"`

Fix: `currency: "USD":'symbol':"1.2-2"`

Reference: https://angular.io/api/common/CurrencyPipe